# Functional style recursion with Guava?

Tags: java, recursion, functional-programming, guava

I have a `MyService` interface with `MyServiceImpl` basic implementation.
I wrap `MyServiceImpl` into a chain of `MyService` decorators.

For that i've created a `MyServiceDelegate` which is an abstract class taking a `MyService` instance and delegating all the service calls to the provided `MyService` instance.

But in my unit tests, for a specific need, i need to find back the first real implementation of the `MyService`, which is `MyServiceImpl`, and i only have a `MyService` which refers to a decorator.

I just wonder if it is possible with Guava, to make a recursion in a functional way that will return me the "original service" that has been decorated with a lot of layers and is not a delegate service.
I think of using a function like Function that returns the delegate service, or null if it's the original service, but don't know were to go with it.

I know i can easily do it with a while loop, and i'm not looking for an alternative solution. Just want to know if Guava can solve these kind of problems.

Comment: Why? The normal way to go about this is to test the smallest element possible. In other words each decorator is tested on it's own, as is the final implementation. Functional testing can test the whole stack, but a functional test really should care about which class is doing what work, just that the work takes place ...

Comment: I know, my decorators are already tested. This is an integration test and i my decorators are needed for test, as part of the classes integration.

Comment: So why does your integration test care what implementation you're using. That way leads to brittle tests. Your integration test should only care whether the whole structure does what you ask it to ...

Comment: Because my test MyService implementation is a mock that record the service calls and i need to retrieve the results. As i can't retrieve the calls through the interface and can't cast the decorator as a RecorderService i need to get the final delegate to be able to cast it to RecorderService and then to retrieve the MyService calls in my unit tests. I can't change this easily.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't even need a while loop or Guava. Just add the following method in your interface:

```
public MyService undecorate();
```

And then the following implementation in the delegate:

```
return decoratedService.undecorate();
```

And the following implementation in the "real" implementation:

```
return this;
```

If the interface can't be modified, do it externally:

```
public MyService undecorate(MyService service) {
    if (service instanceof MyServiceDelegate) {
        return undecorate(((MyServiceDelegate) service).getDecoratedService());
    }
    else {
        return service;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it's still the equivalent of an "alternative solution". There can be many fancy ways to do it, using a visitor for exemple :D but it's not what i'm looking for

Comment: I fail to understand what you're asking, actually. Guava can't magically implement this for you, and since the solution is 3 lines long, I don't really see what it could bring to the table. So I guess the answer is simply No: Guava can't solve this kind of problems.

Comment: Ok so it's what i'm looking for: is there an easier way to do it with Guava.

Comment: @SebastienLorber As clarfified - No.. Also isn't this fairly simple? why you want to do with **only** guava?